# Perl: grep a parent directory

Tags: perl

I am new in Perl and I want to grep a parent directory that contains a specific child dir name under a specific path.

Inputs: child dir name "childDirName" and the path that contains the parent directory "/path/toParentDir/"

Output: the parent directory "parentDir"

I have looked at file::find but I am a overwhelmed because I don't know the full path to the child dir /path/toparentDir/parentDir/childDirName.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want find a directory name which contains a child directory with a specific name. You can do this using [File::Find::Rule](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Find::Rule) :

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find::Rule;

my $dir_to_search = '/path/toParentDir';
my $dir_to_find   = 'childDirName';

my @dirs = File::Find::Rule->directory->mindepth(1)->maxdepth(1)->in( $dir_to_search );
for my $dir ( @dirs ) {
    if ( -d "$dir/$dir_to_find" ) {
        my $rel_dir = $dir =~ s{^\Q$dir_to_search/}{}r;
        say "Parent dir is '$rel_dir'";
    }
}
```

For example, if the directory tree is:

```
/
└── path
    └── toParentDir
        ├── parentDir
        │   └── childDirName
        └── otherDir
            └── notChildDirName
```

The output will be:

```
Parent dir is 'parentDir'
```

Comment: @ikegami Thanks for the edits!

Comment: @ikegami Of course indeed overkill! Updated answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for the useful code! just a quick question because the r at the end of my $rel_dir = $dir =~ s{^\Q$dir_to_search/}{}r;
is causing a synthax error and deleting it it gives me $rel_dir=1 not the name. Is there any other way to get the matching name instead of r? Would you please comment this line? Thank you so much!

Comment: You are welcome! Yes the `r` modifier will not work if you are using an old version of perl. Just use `(my $rel_dir = $dir ) =~ s{^\Q$dir_to_search/}{}` instead

Comment: This works perfectly! Thank you a lot for the great help!